# Oracle Sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, alias

I have 2 tables PORT and shipment. I have to select the NAME corresponding to the max(count). It throws an error for having an ALIAS name 'A'. Is there any mistake in this code or some other alternative available?

```
  select name from
   (
   select name, count(name) as countval from
    (
    select p.name from port p 
    inner join shipment s on p.id =s.departure_port_id
    )
   group by name
    order by countval desc
        ) A 
      where countval=(select max(countval) from A));
```

Comment: the title is meaningless,contains a typo an the error message is missing. But if Oracle throws an error I would assume that there is an error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank` window function. The result would give you multiple names in case there are ties for max count.

```
select name from (
select p.name,rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rnk
from port p 
join shipment s on p.id =s.departure_port_id
group by p.name
) t  
where rnk=1
```

Comment: Thanks man,,, would appreciate if you could suggest a way to use Max and Min function to retrieve the ans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use having fr filter the result you can use

```
select name from (
  select p.name, count(p.name) my_count from port p 
  inner join shipment s on p.id =s.departure_port_id
  group by p.name ) t 
having t.my_count = max(t.my_count)
group by name
```

Comment: The syntax looks wrong overall. Whatever `t` is, do you then have a `HAVING` clause **before** the `GROUP BY` clause? Perhaps you meant to write something else?

Comment: thank yu.. but i get the below error

SQL ERROR: 
  group by name ) t
           *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: SQL ERROR: 
            group by name ) t
           * 
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Answer (score 0):

You want the port name for the port with most shipments? This can be several in case of ties. One way is to aggregate the shipping table to get those port numbers and use these to select the port name. This is Oracle 12c:

```
select name
from port 
where id in 
(
  select departure_port_id
  from shipment 
  group by departure_port_id
  order by count(*) desc
  fetch first 1 row with ties
);
```

In earlier versions you would use `RANK` instead to rank yor shipment aggregates, which is slightly less readable. E.g.:

```
select name
from port 
where (id, 1) in 
(
  select departure_port_id, rank() over (order by count(*) desc)
  from shipment 
  group by departure_port_id
);
```

Comment: Nice way of using `rank()` with a semi-join!